# Postfix TLS Roundcube problems

Tags: linux, ssl, postfix, roundcube, starttls

im writing this because i have a problem when i try to test SMTP with Roundcube. Before i had no problem with Postfix ou Dovecot.
It seems like it's a TLS problem :

[SMTP Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVirv.png)

When i look in my log file i have this :

[log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPM4f.png)

Contrariwise the IMAP test is working fine.

From what i research , it's seems like it's because i my certificate is a self-signed certificate and i have to add an exception so that my certificate get trusted.

But i have no idea how to do that and i didn't find the answer on the web.

My config files :

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/mailserver.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/mailserver.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated        defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = debian.locaheb.fr
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname

mydestination = srvmess.locaheb.fr, debian.locaheb.fr, localhost.locaheb.fr,   localhost
#mydestination = srvmess, debian, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
#virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox- domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox- domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf

smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated     reject_unauth_destination 
 virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

> 

```
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
-o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
-o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
-o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
 # ====================================================================
 # Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
 # pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
 #
 # Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
 # agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
 # and other message envelope options.
 # ====================================================================
 #
  # maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
 # Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
 #
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
 # Specify in cyrus.conf:
 #   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
 #
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension}  ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
 # ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
 #
 # Other external delivery methods.
 #
 ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
 flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
 bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
 flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender  $recipient
 scalemail-backend unix -   n   n   -   2   pipe
flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store  ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
 mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
 ${nexthop} ${user}

 dovecot   unix    -    n    n    -      -     pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f ${sender}  -d ${recipient}
```

Comment: Alright i found out how to do it !

Comment: why are you using self signed certs?